# API design: Best way to hide data model object from user?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, idioms

I am working on a simple API in C++ where the end user of my code will pass an instance of a `UserProfile` class around to various other classes for modification. The user profile has a very basic public interface, with the data stored in a private pimpl object. I then add implementation classes as friends so they can access the internal data structure, which is defined in a separate implementation file. The basic outline of this class looks as follows . . .

```
// For pimpl here
class UserProfileData;

class UserProfile
{
public:
    /// ctor to allocate impl
    UserProfile();

    /// dtor 
    ~UserProfile();

    /// Do some very simple stuff with a few methods
    std::string getProfileName() const;

private:
    /// Use pimpl and hide impl so API user can just use simplified interface
    std::unique_ptr<UserProfileData> userProfileData;

    /// Allow implementation classes access to userProfileData
    friend class ClassOne;
    friend class ClassTwo;
};
```

Building a big list of friend classes doesn't feel like the most elegant solution for hiding the data from the API user. It seems a little smelly. Are there any patterns or idioms that will allow me to achieve the same goal differently?

Comment: Most of the time, anything `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo` need should be `public`. You are yourself a user of your API.

Comment: There's not enough specifics here to choose between the various options.  Why not, for instance, just have a public accessor function for userProfileData and just leave the UserProfileData undefined for the people who shouldn't have access?  What use case are you trying to prevent?

Answer (score 3):

Think about what you're trying to achieve by hiding the implementation details of your `UserProfile` class. From the sounds of it, you're probably working to decouple consumers from the internal structure of the data. Doing this with the data container *may* be more trouble than it's worth, though.

Purely from the consumer's perspective, there's no need to hide the details of a class like this. Consider the following data types:

```
    struct ProfileData
    {
        std::string profileName;
    }

    struct ProfileDataWithHiddenDetails
    {
        std::string getProfileName();
    }
```

The purpose of each of these types is straightforward: they're used to transmit profile information between interested parties. Each type suits this purpose well, but one is much simpler to reason about than the other.

Does `getProfileName` communicate with a database? Does it retrieve the profile name from a deep hierarchy of values? Is the profile name just stored in a member variable? Any of these (among others) is possible; the information has been purposefully hidden from the consumer.

The first question is: **Does this information *need* to be hidden from the consumer?** If the consumer is using the object as a data container, then abstractions would only get in the way.

If your intent is to indeed hide details of the data structure, the next question is: ***What* information do you need to hide from the consumer?** If the object is not a simple data aggregator, consumers will need to adopt a different mindset when using it.

Abstractions can make it easier to reason about a system, but they can also make it harder. Try to abstract the *behavior* in your API rather than the *data*.

---

#### Example

Imagine `ProfileDataWithHiddenDetails::getProfileName` actually retrieves the profile name from a rich object model that you wanted to keep hidden from consumers. Something like:

```
    std::string getProfileName
    {
        return objectModel.getRoot().getUserProfile().profileName;
    }
```

These details don't need to be hidden in the implementation of `getProfileName`. Perhaps there was an API function call that returned the profile data:

```
    ProfileDataWithHiddenDetails getProfileData()
    {
        return ProfileDataWithHiddenDetails(objectModel);
    }
```

Instead of returning an abstraction, this API function could handle the abstraction itself:

```
    ProfileData getProfileData()
    {
        auto profileName = objectModel.getRoot().getUserProfile().profileName;

        return ProfileData { profileName };
    }
```